Which is the correct method to make a watch bracelet with modifiers
I'm trying to make a bracelet for a watch, I have used 2 methods. And need further information which is the correct method. I've seen some tutorials on YT, very sloppy skills, with no regards to actual watch making.
1st method uses 2 modifiers, array, with focus on the object offset using empty and curve modifier, which makes the bracelet look more correct, the start of the bracelet is wider, and it becomes less wide as it gets closer to the folder over clasp(sample).
The downside of using this method is, its in 3 different parts, top part of the bracelet, down part of the bracelet and Folding clasp manually positioned.




The second method, I had to apply the array modifiers and join the bracelet, use proportional editing tool to make the ends less wider with the Folding clasp, and make it one solid object, and then using the curve modifier, wrap the bracelet around the Bezier curve. But this method squashed the bracelet, and need lots of adjusting to try get it correct. Also since the array modifier was applied, there was no way to play with the distance if I needed to make some changes.



So I'm here for you guys to guide me with the best advice on which method is best.

I don't see the downside of the first method tbh. If anything you probably want the clasp to be separate because it's a more complex part and would deform with a curve modifier so it's easier to just place it manually.
There's way to make chain like objects that don't deform following a curve but it starts getting really complicated. If the first method gives the results you want I don't think there's any downsides to it

For the second method, if you want to use it. Instead of using proportional editing in Edit mode, you can use a Lattice modifier on the band. (Look up a tutorial on youtube if you don't know what those are yet). If you parent the lattice to the band you can still move it around to position it in the curve without having to apply the deformation

Hi there. After some further more seeing about which method has better result. I saw that with the offset using empty is not good with parts which use latches and links. As you can see in my example, the smaller a pattern gets, its moving the links (Red Arrows). I will try using a Lattice modifier, and try to locate YT tutorials. But most tutorials I saw, are not precise, and not based on real watch making methods.
https://ibb.co/0cxbbLZ

I tried the lattice method, and seems to give them best result so far. Thanks for your insight.
https://ibb.co/DQgYSgG
https://ibb.co/mH96stN
